# How do you get an event for every unhandled exception in a mixed WinForms/WPF application

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms

I want to get an event for every unhandled excpetion in my application, so I can write it to a log file. The application started as a Windows Forms application, where this can easily be done by subscribing the static `System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadException` event and calling `System.Windows.Forms.Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode`.

In a pure WPF application, it's easy too, I just have to subscribe the `System.Windows.Application` instance's `DispatcherUnhandledException` event.

But how can I do this for a mixed application (i.e. a Windows Forms application with some WPF dialog windows and controls), where I don't have a global `System.Windows.Application` instance? `System.Windows.Application.Current` is `null` at startup, when I try to subscribe the event. I've tried creating my own instance of `System.Windows.Application`, but apparently it gets destroyed when the first WPF window is closed. If I try to open another WPF window after that, I get an `EngineExecutionException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this -

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(MyHandler);
```

Comment: Refer to this link- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't catch exceptions in WPF event handlers.

Comment: Try setting unhandled exception mode like this before hooking the event -
Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);

Comment: And for UI thread exceptions you can hook this event -
Application.ThreadException += new System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);